# Trying to get date format in Google Sheets to display as 1st, 2nd, 3rd etc with the relevant suffix using google scripts editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to get the date format currently displaying as Monday 25 @ 7:30 PM but I would like it to display showing the relevant suffix i.e. 'th' or 'st' or 'nd' i.e. 4th, 1st, 2nd etc.

I am using the code below but getting the error message "Exception: Invalid argument: date. Should be of type: Date" any ideas? Much apprecitated

```
 function getOrdinal(date) {
    var d = new Date(),
    suffix = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][(d > 3 && d < 21) || d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : d % 10];

return Utilities.formatDate(date, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "d'" + suffix + "MMMM, yyyy");
}
```

[image]

Comment: if `date` is `Monday 25 @ 7:30 PM` then that's not a valid `date` object. Could you show the code you define `date` ?

Comment: The date shows as that but in google sheets is written as: 1/25/2021 19:30:00, even when I change the front-end format to be the same as this it presents the same issue.  Thanks Marios

Comment: Just to clarify, your input is `Monday 25 @ 7:30 PM` and you want `25th January, 2021`

Comment: Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: Yes Marios I want it to be Monday 25th January 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

Your goal is to convert the date in the sheet to `Monday 25th January 2021`.

- You can use your current solution to obtain `25th` and then use `Utilities.formatDate` to obtain day, month and year.
- [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) were used to concatenate the resulting string.

### Code snippet:

Execute `myFunction` to paste the new format in column `M` assuming the data input is in column `L` (see screenshot):

```
function myFunction(){
 const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); // put the name of your sheet
 const dts = sh.getRange('L1:L6').getValues().flat();
 const new_dts = dts.map(c=>[getOrdinal(c)]);
 sh.getRange(1,13,new_dts.length,1).setValues(new_dts);
}


function getOrdinal(input) {
 const dt = new Date(input);
 const d = dt.getDate();
 const suffix = ['th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd'][(d > 3 && d < 21) || d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : d % 10]; 
 const dayN = Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "EEEE");
 const ds = d+suffix;
 const rd = Utilities.formatDate(dt, Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MMMM yyyy");
 return `${dayN} ${ds} ${rd}`;
}
```

### Example sheet of code snippet:

[image]

Comment: I have just added a screenshot that shows the output format vs the original entered format, could you use the code based on the entered format rather than the output format as I believe it won't work otherwise?

Comment: @BenWillis I updated my answer. Let me know if it worked for you and if it did  feel free to confirm the answer.

Comment: Thank you Marios, also any idea how I can get it to also show the time at the end? i.e. Monday 25th January 2021 @ 7:30pm?

Comment: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) is the table. I guess you can replace `MMMM yyyy` with something like `MMMM yyyy @ hhhh:mmmm aaaa` . I am not sure if it will work liike that though but you can try (Use one or 4 letters etc). If it does not work, please post a new question and post the link here. @BenWillis